# Can't connect externally to Windows PPTP VPN

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, pptp

I'm trying to setup the basic Windows PPTP VPN so I can access temporarily access my home network while I will be away.  My laptop can connect to the VPN Server when on the same network using the VPN server' private address(192.168.0.66), but I'm unable to connect to the VPN server when I use the IP my ISP assigns me.  My router is a Motorola SBG6580.  I've forward port 1723 to my VPN server and have enabled PPTP passthrough.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The port might be blocked by your ISP. You may try to set a port forwarding from another port.

Comment: I have Comcast and from what I've read online they don't sound like they block PPTP.  I've tried forwarding from another port as well with no luck.  I wondering if PPTP Passthrough isn't fully supported by my router model...

Comment: If you want to make sure, you can connect your VPN server straight to the Internet and check if the connection is working. You're going to be able to isolate whether this has something to do with your router.